# @Input-less OnPush Components in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I have a scenario where I have @Input-less `OnPush` component in Angular. If I call `markForCheck()`, the view binding in my component's template will be checked?

I mean, my component is `OnPush` and `markForCheck()` marks all ancestors to be checked and because my component has no @Input, what will be the behaviour of Angular here? Will Angular skip checking component's view bindings or will it always check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the source code example from `ChangeDetectorRef`. The *view* shows the value `numberOfTicks` which is updated when `markForCheck()` is called. Notice that the component has no `@Input()` bindings.

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'cmp',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    template: `Number of ticks: {{numberOfTicks}}`
  })
  class Cmp {
    numberOfTicks = 0;

    constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.numberOfTicks++;
        // the following is required, otherwise the view will not be updated
        this.ref.markForCheck();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting and explaining it with an appropriate example. I have just a small question. Imagine, `Cmp` has some `inputs` which haven't changed and same code gets called. Will `markForCheck()` still checks `Cmp` in that scenario for changes or it will just skip it because it has `ChangeDetection` set to `OnPush` and that `inputs` haven't changed?

Comment: @ImranLatif `markForCheck` will set a flag on the view that it's dirty no matter what the inputs are. `detectChanges` will execute change detection immediately. Both methods update the HTML of the template. `ngOnChanged`  for the interface `OnChanges` is called only when `@Input()` has changed. I think this might be your confusion. There is a difference between `@Input()` bindings and the **view**. The view is what renders the template. The template gets rendered when it's marked *dirty*. `markForCheck` manually sets the dirty flag. `ON_PUSH` sets it only when inputs changed.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation @cgTag.